# Null value in primary key of hibernate entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, entity

I faced with problem of null value in PK.

Here's an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="space")
public class Space implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private UserAccount user;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date createdTime;
    private Date modifiedTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="space")
    private Set<SpaceAccess> spaceAccesses = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<SpaceAccess> getSpaceAccesses() {
        return spaceAccesses;
    }

    public void setSpaceAccesses(Set<SpaceAccess> spaceAccesses) {
        this.spaceAccesses = spaceAccesses;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Space() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserAccount getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserAccount user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getCreatedTime() {
        return createdTime;
    }

    public void setCreatedTime(Date createdTime) {
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
    }

    public Date getModifiedTime() {
        return modifiedTime;
    }

    public void setModifiedTime(Date modifiedTime) {
        this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
    }
}
```

I wrote strategy to generate PK properly but I always get Null in id field when I create new instance of the Space:

```
Space space = new Space();
```

Here's content of the object:

[image]

What i should do to generate id of instance properly using hibernate/spring mechanisms?

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url="some_url"
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

P.S. I use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa with version: 2.3.4.RELEASE.

Comment: UPD: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) gives the same result.

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: PostgreSQL10Dialect

Comment: Do you use hibernate [schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation) tool?

Comment: Actually, an entity id will be generated after [entity saving](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites)

Comment: It seems to be. Does it make automatically?

Comment: But I can't save entity because i get NPE: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.webapp.domain.Space.getId(Space.java:49) ~[main/:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]

Comment: Could you please show your `application.properties` and full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a problem, because my getId() returned a primitive long. That was a problem.